# Passing arguments to a DataProvider method using TestNG

Tags: testng

Given my data CSV file:

```
jones;1293039,
smith;2938949,
johnson;1203939,
clark;8293044
```

And my DataProvider:

```java
@DataProvider(name="data")
public Iterator<Object[]> custDataProvider(){
    try{
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(CSV_FILE)).useDelimiter(DELIMITER);
        return new Iterator<Object[]>() {
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return scanner.hasNext();
            }

            @Override
            public Object[] next() {
                return new Object[]{scanner.next().split(";")[0]};
            }
        };
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I can iterate over the data values based on the index of the array, splitting on the `;` So, the below method will print the `name` attribute at index 0:

```java
@Test(dataProvider = "data")
public void createNewCustomer(String name) {
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

And if I change the array index to `[1]` it will print the customer number. But I wonder if I can parameterize the `DataProvider` method with an `int index` like so:-

```java
@DataProvider(name="data")
public Iterator<Object[]> custDataProvider(int index){
    try{
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(CSV_FILE)).useDelimiter(DELIMITER);
        return new Iterator<Object[]>() {
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return scanner.hasNext();
            }

            @Override
            public Object[] next() {
                return new Object[]{scanner.next().split(";")[index]};
            }
        };
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
         return null;
    }
}
```

And call based on whether I want the customer name or number like so:-

```java
@Test(dataProvider = "data")
public void createNewCustomer(String name) {
    String customerName = custDataProvider(0);
    System.out.println(name);
}

@Test(dataProvider = "data")
public void createNewCustomer(String number) {
    String customerNumber = custDataProvider(1);
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

The behavior I'm seeing is that it skips the tests entirely.

Comment: Assume that you can. How are you going to pass index number **to** your data provider? From where?

Comment: What about you read the file, create a data structure, and walk through this structure, passing each element to a function that performs the check you want? @DataProvider requires basically the same support code and adds a bunch of limitations; totally bloated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify a number like you do, but you can use reflection and customize `@DataProvider` behavior depending on the method it runs. As per [TestNG documentation](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders):

> If you declare your @DataProvider as taking a java.lang.reflect.Method as first parameter, TestNG will pass the current test method for this first parameter. This is particularly useful when several test methods use the same @DataProvider and you want it to return different values depending on which test method it is supplying data for.

Answer (score 1):

Don't change input argument of `custDataProvider` method. Use `custDataProvider` without any input arguments. Just change the input arguments of `createNewCustomer` from `String` to `Iterator`. Exactly like whatever you return from `custDataProvider`.

Then you can iterate through it in `createNewCustomer`.

```java
       @DataProvider(name="data")
    public Iterator<Object[]> custDataProvider(){
        try{
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(CSV_FILE)).useDelimiter(DELIMITER);
            return new Iterator<Object[]>() {
                @Override
                public boolean hasNext() {
                    return scanner.hasNext();
                }
    
                @Override
                public Object[] next() {
                    return new Object[]{scanner.next().split(";")[0]};
                }
            };
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }


    @Test(dataProvider = "data")
    public void createNewCustomer(Iterator<Object[]> names) {
        while(names.hasNext()){
            //Do what ever you want
        }

    }
```